# When a detection tool fires no alert, how to tell the difference if the environment is safe or just something is wrong with the tool

Tags: antivirus, validation

For example, if an antivirus gives no alert for a couple of months, how do you confirm if the antivirus is working to prevent viruses, and not just hung?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "false negative".

Answer (score 3):

You test it with simulated malware.

This could be anything from a simple [EICAR](https://www.eicar.org/download-anti-malware-testfile/) test file (to confirm that it's actually running and doing what it should) through to red-team style engagements where you have people developing and deploying custom "malware" implants in your network to see if they're detected.